# Как сменить юрл главной на внутреннюю WP

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на движке wp, нужно чтобы при входе на сайт открывалась не главная, а страница с рубрикой( вместо site.ru , site.ru/rubrika) - сделал через редирект, но скорей всего не то. Страницы главной как таковой нету, так что нужно чтоб сайт индексировался считая главной site.ru/rubrika

Comment: Выведи на главную вывод рубрики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[template_redirect](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/template_redirect)

```
// functions.php
function my_homepage_redirect() {
    if (is_home()) {
        wp_redirect(get_category_link($id)); // $id = id категории
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_homepage_redirect');
```

[хороший ответ на похожий вопрос](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/how-to-make-a-category-page-the-blog-home-page)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте это просто в админке. В админке wp есть возможность назначить любую страницу в роли главной.ВНешний вид -> Настроить -> Настройка главной страницы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]